# Replace element in array by average

Tags: c++, arrays, replace, average

I have a question about the exercise from my course:
Write a program that takes array of real numbers as parameter and replaces each element that is smaller than average of the first and last element, by this average. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void replaverage(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i; i < 6; i++) {
        cout << "Enter the numbers" << endl;
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    int f = arr[0];
    int l = arr[n - 1];
    double av = f + l / 2;
    for (int i; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < av) {
            arr[i] = av;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int arr[n];
    replaverage(arr, n);
    cout << arr << " " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Code is working, however as an output, it is giving some kind of address "0x7fff2306a5c0". I'm beginner so I apologize, maybe my error is stupid but I don't know how to fix it. Thanks for helping!

Comment: The reason why you're printing out an address is because your `cout<<arr` is printing exactly what it is supposed to print: the address of the object `arr`. If you want to print the content of such array, for example its content, try to iterate over it and print each of its positions. Also, there are many other flaws in your code, such as declaring `n` but not assigning a value to it (so, what's the real size of `arr` since `n` is not defined? UB!), for instance. I also strongly recommend you to take a look at the `vector` STL container for your problem.

Comment: also your average is calculated wrong. it should be (f + l) / 2. Otherwise it will do l/2 + f... your loop is not initializing i, so it should be for(int i = 0; ....

Comment: Oh I undrestand. Thanks :)

Comment: *"Code is working"* - no, it isn't. This code invokes *undefined behavior*. First, the C++ standard doesn't support variable-length native arrays (which is what `arr` is in `main`). Even if your toolchain *does* extend support, it's still wrong, as the value of `n` must be determined *prior* to the variable-length array declaration, which it is not. From what I see, there is no need for a VLA in this code in the first place. The hard-coding of `6` as the count of values in your function suggests a simple native `int arr[6];` would be sufficient. If you need dynamic, use a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void replaverage(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Enter the number: "; 
        cin >> arr[i];
        cout << endl;
    }
    int f = arr[0];
    int l = arr[n - 1];
    double av = (f + l) / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < av) {
            arr[i] = av;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n = 6; // Making 6 since you had it hardcoded
    int arr[n];
    replaverage(arr, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- First problem: Initialize your loop counters to 0;
- Second problem: Initialize n in main being passed as parameter to
  something
- Third problem: Your average calculation is incorrect. It should be (f+l) / 2. Otherwise it will be doing l/2 + f, which is incorrect.
- Fourth problem: You need to loop over your array to see all the
  elements

Comment: @Bartek, feel free to accept the answer if it has answered your question. This will help others see the answer that answered the question accordingly.

Comment: Just a heads up: don't see why `#include <string>` is necessary. Also, `using namespace std;` isn't really a good approach, and using VLA's instead of `std::vector`, isn't that recommended as well (see @WhozCraig comment above). Anyway, this serves the purpose, but still not being the best approach.

Comment: @woz, agreed. However, assuming this is what they are teaching in class at this level. Usually they don't explain these things till later on.

Comment: @Bartek, if you are feeling confident, you should attempt to create another function to print your array instead of having the loop in main. It should be same concept now that you have a better understanding!

Comment: @OmidCompSCI got your point, but it doesn't mean that we shouldn't take it as an opportunity to explain new ones about some perks of the language. I'm not trying to be the "smart a**" here, just pointing out that there are always room for studying and improving :)

Comment: @woz, completely agreed!